# Refresh page using cache

Tags: javascript, caching, refresh

I am trying to refresh a page, but WANT to use the cache and can't figure out how to do this. There are two situations:

- If I click in the URL bar and hit enter (or visit the page from somewhere else) it reloads the page/images from the cache. **GREAT!**
- If I click on the refresh button or use Javascript to refresh the page it grabs all the images again and takes forever. **NOT GREAT!**

I've tried: `top.location.reload(false);` and `top.location.reload(true);` (I'm sending this from in an iFrame) and neither used the cache. I'm avoiding using `location` so it doesn't end up in the browser history twice.

**Question**: How do I reload the page using the cached images? Is there a different javascript function or is this a mod_expires issue?

Thanks for any help in advance!

*EDIT: (info from chrome: developer tools)*

- When navigating to the page I get "From Cache" for all images
- When refreshing page I get "304 - Not Modified" for all images (and it takes the time to download each)

*EDIT 2: (Headers from an image, safari: developer tools)*

**Javascript: top.location.reload(false); (No Cache!)**

```
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Request Headers
Cache-Control:max-age=0
If-Modified-Since:Tue, 28 Jun 2011 07:13:17 GMT
If-None-Match:"104684ae-a7d-66e41d40"
Referer:http://getdirectus.com/dev/media.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1

Response Headers
Cache-Control:max-age=157680000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Tue, 28 Jun 2011 16:56:50 GMT
Etag:"104684ae-a7d-66e41d40"
Expires:Sun, 26 Jun 2016 16:56:50 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=94
Server:Apache/2.0.54
```

**Navigating to page: (Uses cache)**

```
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers**
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=157680000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:2685
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Tue, 28 Jun 2011 16:54:20 GMT
Etag:"104684ae-a7d-66e41d40"
Expires:Sun, 26 Jun 2016 16:54:20 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified:Tue, 28 Jun 2011 07:13:17 GMT
Server:Apache/2.0.54
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not grasping this, but what is the point of a "refresh" if you want to retain the cache?

Comment: And it can be a) server expiration and/or b) client expiration (no or small cache) not to forget c) some random value added to the URL because you wanted to keep the images out of cache but forgot about it. Download firebug, click on the NET tab and see the headers

Comment: @Brad - Specifically, it is for a media thumbnail page. After I upload a new image within an AJAXed iFrame I want to refresh the page... but each time I do it reloads ALL the images on the page NOT from the server. Technically it should _only_ have to load the newly uploaded image.

Comment: @cbh: that's a different question! You want to cache the images in the client

Comment: @mplungjan - Thanks, it's not a client-side expiration issue since it has no problem using the cache for the (whole) page until I hit the refresh button. There are no query strings or anything after the filename... as for server expiration, so would this be an htaccess fix?

Comment: @levu - Agreed, but same question. It _is_ caching them on the client... if I _navigate_ to this page it works perfectly (using the cache). The issue is specific to hitting the refresh button (or calling refresh from js).

Comment: If the client caches the images, you can safely reload the page and the client has the images stored. If the client doesn't cache images, you can't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for `window.location.reload( false );` says it will load from cache. If that isn't happening then you may be seeing a browser bug. See if you can replicate the problem in another browser.

EDIT (for your edit): You are seeing that behaviour because you don't have an Expires header set in the future. You will need to [add an Expires header in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html).

Comment: @SpliFF - Thanks, I have added an htaccess file with the following in it: `ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/jpg "modification plus 5 years"` (all my thumbnails are jpgs) and the same issue persists. Still getting "304  - Not Modified" on refresh. Any ideas?

Comment: use `access plus 5 years`. using `modification` requires constantly asking the server if the resource was modified (hence the 304 response)

Comment: @SpliFF - I have switched it over to `access` and the problem persists with the same status returns. Could it be that hitting the refresh button _forces_ the browser not to use the cache?

Comment: yes, that's right. Physically hitting refresh button always sends `Cache-Control: no-cache`

Comment: @SpliFF - Ok, well back to the initial question, why is it `no-cache`ing my javascript refreshes? Could it be due to the request coming from an iFrame?

Comment: Also, I am using `top.location.reload(false)` not `top.location.refresh(false)`, could this be the issue? When I try refresh it no longer works.

Comment: iframe doesn't matter and `top.location.reload(false)` is correct. if you fixed that mod_expires code then it should already be working. Maybe clear your cache and restart apache before retrying to make sure you don't have any old headers.

Comment: @SpliFF - Fair enough, I am on a shared server so I can't restart apache (I'll have to wait until it's next cycle). But I ensured a clear cache and it still is happening.

Comment: if you're really using .htaccess then a restart isn't required. either way you should check with Firebug or Safari/Chrome Net panels that the Expires header is really being set.

Comment: @SpliFF - First off, thank you for all this help. I really appreciate it. I have included the headers in the post. The `expires` value seems to prove that the htaccess is being read. I'm at a loss as to what to check now.

Comment: @SpliFF - Also, I have tested `top.location = top.location;` and it uses the cache, are there any issues with switching all my `top.location.reload(false);` to that to avoid the 304? Are there any compatibility issues with this method?

Comment: I don't see any issue with that approach. It seems to me that the browser you are using exhibits some odd behaviour with reload (seems to ignore the cache=false argument). If you find `top.location = top.location` gives you issues you could try `top.location.replace(top.location)` which explicitly does not add a new history entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

If the location contains a `#`, be sure to remove it before setting `href`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable caching in the client, mind sending `Expire` headers, e.g. with [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

Comment: I have set the `expire` in an htaccess file (see the headers in the post) and the problem persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using [this site](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache-test/), I only got green image with `location.refresh(true);`. With `location.refresh();` or `location.refresh(false);` I got the red image. Working ok, I guess.

Comment: @Raven - Haha, is it bad that I went and saw red... then hit refresh and the image is broken? If I shift-refresh or navigate there again I see it as green... but it's broken on all refreshes. (I cleared my cache)

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate things to consider here:

1: the request... browser -> server

2: the response... server -> browser

When you refresh a page you cannot get around the browser doing a requests for page assets to the server.

What you can do is make sure the server sends a minimal response.

The best way to achieve this, is to use [**etags**](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/03/http-etag-explained/) in your response headers. That way the browser will send a `if-none-match` request to the server, and get a `304 Nothing changed` response back assuming nothing has been modifed.

Comment: I seemingly have etags in my headers (see edits within post) and _am_ getting `304 Not Modified` on javascript refresh. But the page still takes the time to load all images (not from cache like when navigating to the page). Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the images have etags? you need to have etags on all assets you don't wish to be loaded again

Answer (score 0):

Your second request was initiated by manually refreshing the page. When you do this, the browser sends up an additional `cache-control:max-age=0` header with the request. This is where the 304 (Not Modified) is coming from.

If you navigate within the site (using links), the browser will continue to use its cache.